# how do I access object "player" inside the array retrofit 2 / android studio

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2, rapidapi

I would like to unmarshal a list of players from this nested json using retrofit 2 and Gson in android:

```json
{
    "api": {
        "status": 200,
        "message": "GET players/playerId/44",
        "results": 1,
        "filters": [
            ...
        ],
        "players": [
            {
                "firstName": "Kent",
                "lastName": "Bazemore",
                "teamId": "29",
                "yearsPro": "7",
                "collegeName": "Old Dominion",
                "leagues": {
                    "standard": {
                        "jersey": "24",
                        "active": "1",
                        "pos": "G-F"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Retrofit, I would advise you to look into Gson/Jackson/Moshi converters. These help in converting your JSON responses to plain Java objects.

You should then be able to access it as

```
api.getPlayers() -> array of players
```

Answer (score 0):

You first need to create a model class then you can access the particular key. For example:

```
public class ResponseItem {


private int status;
private String message;
private List<String> players;

public int getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(int status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
}

public List<String> getPlayers() {
    return players;
}

public void setPlayers(List<String> players) {
    this.players = players;
}
```

Add the following code snippet in your retrofit method:

```
if (response.isSuccessful()) {
  ResponseItem responseItem;
  responseItem = response.body(); 
}
```

P.S. Make sure to complete the model class using the same pattern.